# Element.Visible returning false, but it is visible on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following if-statement, that occurs on Page.IsPostBack, why is FirstName.Visible, LastName.Visible, EmailAddress.Visible all false?:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainLogo.InnerHtml = ModuleEval("HeadlineLandingPage").ToString();
    FillLabelsAndImages();

    if (!Page.IsPostBack) //Page load
    {
        //Some random code here
    }
    else //Submit button load
    {
        MainLogo.InnerHtml = ModuleEval("HeadlineLandingMasterPage").ToString();
            if (FirstName.Visible && LastName.Visible && EmailAddress.Visible) 
            {
                if (detailsResponse.ResponseStatus.Success && detailsResponse.MemberInfo != null)
                {
                     //Random code here
                }
                else
                    HandleWebServiceError(detailsResponse.ResponseStatus);
            }
            else 
            {
            }
    }
}
```

The elements are invisible by default:

```
<input type="text" id="FirstName" runat="server" visible="False" />
```

However they are set to visible when some user actions occur:

```
    FirstName.Visible = true;
```

The elements are all clearly visible when I submit, I don't understand why asp.net still thinks they are invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you changing the control?

If you've got something to the effect of

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FirstName.Visible && LastName.Visible && EmailAddress.Visible) 
    {
        //Code
    }
}

protected void UpdateFirstName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FirstName.Visible = true;
}
```

And you call the update by using an ASP.NET event, such as

```
<asp:button text="Button!" onclick="UpdateFirstName" runat="server" />
```

When you click on the button Page_Load is called first.  While Page_Load is running,

```
FirstName.Visible
```

Would be whatever the default value is - in this case, false.

Unfortunately there isn't really a way to call UpdateFirstName before Page_Load.

The best solution is to move your

```
if(FirstName.Visible && LastName.Visible && EmailAddress.Visible)
```

logic into a different function which can be called after UpdateFirstName runs.

Comment: I update the visibility to visible in:     if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    {
        //Some random code here
    }

Comment: So you're only setting the visibility to true the first time you load the page, not during postback?

Comment: I believe the state of elements should stay the same on postback.

Comment: Sadly it won't - every time the page is built, it starts from the default (the .aspx definitions), then modifies it from there. Try removing the if(!this.IsPostBack) and replace the else with if(this.IsPostBack), and it should work as expected.

Comment: The code in this answer reminded me/made me realize I could just have `Element.Property` rather than `Element.Property == Boolean` in my if statements in ASP.NET; thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Elements rendered via asp.net controls will not render in the page at all if they are set to visible=false. IE: The element will not be in the output.

Regular html elements do not understand this and therefore you must set style="display:none" to hide them while still making them available in the DOM/rendered output.

So if what you are using is not an asp.net control setting the value visible="false" on the element, as you show for your input element:

```
<input type="text" id="FirstName" runat="server" visible="False" />
```

Really does nothing except placing an attribute on the element called visible which has a value of False.

For example:

If I put the following in an asp.net page.

```
<input id="test" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="test1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then on the server side I run the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.Style.Add("display", "none");
    test1.Visible = false;
}
```

The rendered output will be something similar to this:

```
<input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$test" type="text" id="FeaturedContent_test" style="display:none;" />
```

With no sign of the element test1 in the rendered output.
While the element test is in the output except that it does not appear as a visible element on the page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Putting visible="False" does hide the element from being rendered. Like in this case: <input type="text" id="FirstName" runat="server" visible="False" />

Comment: I stand corrected, apparently it will hide it just like a an asp.net control, by not rendering it at all in the page. Or so my quick test would suggest.

Comment: You are correct. Any html control can be used as a server control simply by adding `runat=server`. Setting their visibility to false causes ASP.NET to not render them to the page at all. Therefore you  cannot access those element on the client with JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
if (FirstName.Visible == true && LastName.Visible == true && EmailAddress.Visible ==  true)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Your testing against a boolean and it really shouldn't matter but it's worth a try. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx) the .Visible property "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control and all its child controls are displayed.". So your getting the value but you still need to test against that value.

Comment: I have tried that actually, the problem is that FirstName.Visible is false, so if you use == true, it will be false.

Comment: Ok well that was worth a try. However, if you submit the form with a button click or some other event then the code in the event handler is going to run, not the page load code. Are you using a server control button to submit the form?

Comment: No, I am using the standard html button: <input type="submit" runat="server" text="Enter Now" id="SubmitEntry" value="submit" />

Comment: I am not sure how it works with using a standard html button to submit an ASP.NET form as I have never done that. I am not sure that the ASP server control states are preserved on postback. Can you use a server control such as `<asp:Button>` to submit the form and then place your code inside the event handler for that button?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot because of the way the page was designed before me. I found a way around that if-statement though. Thanks for the effort.